# Particle Sim does not look the same in render as in viewport

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a smoke effect, but some portions of the smoke just aren't appearing in the render. I created a mesh object cloud for the simulation to be rendered to, along with a wind field pointing upwards to simulate smoke being generated into the air, and duplicated both to go on both rear tires of the car. I baked all dynamics, but in the render, the "smoke" mesh seems to not have a trail like in the viewport. It sort of sticks to the tires. I also enabled Disk Cache but it didnt do anything regarding the problem.

First picture is the viewport of what the smoke clouds should look like in the render. Second picture is what I'm getting when I render the same frame.
[image: viewport smoke particle simulation]

[image: same frame rendered]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: i know you are new here, but maybe you can understand that just 2 pictures won't help us to help you.  So please provide provide blend file so we can check it out and so we are able to help you, else we can just guess.

Comment: Did you bake the simulation? Sometimes Blender messes up particle (and other) simulations if they are not baked before rendering, because it loses information between frames.